# Start FBX animation with Tpose

Tags: animation

I downloaded an FBX from Mixamo that has a running animation that starts like this. [image]

I need it to start in a Tpose and transition slowly to the running animation. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to be in Pose mode with your armature selected.

In the Dope Sheet Editor, select all the keys (<kbd>A</kbd>) and move them some frames to the right. (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>25</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> for 25 frames = 1 second)

Go to frame 1, in the 3D View select all the bones, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to reinitialize position and location. The rig should be in T pose now.

Select all the bones, in the 3D View press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert a key on location and rotation (LocRot).

Comment: just made an acc to upvote this, can confirm working in 2019/03/25 using Blender 2.8